# Joining sublists of nested list based on sublist position

Tags: list-manipulation

I have nested list with sublists of varying lengths like this:

```
list={{a,b,c,d},{e,f},{g,h,i},{j},{k,l},{m,n,o}}
```

How can I join the 4th and 5th sublists based on their position to give me:

```
{{a,b,c,d},{e,f},{g,h,i},{j,k,l},{m,n,o}}
```

The closest I have managed to get is using:

```
FlattenAt[list, {{4}, {5}}]
```

But this gives:

```
{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, j, k, l, {m, n, o}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `SubsetMap` (available from version 12.0), but since it requires you to return the same size you get, we could trick it by `Hold` and `Nothing`:

```
ReleaseHold @ SubsetMap[{Join @@ #, Hold @ Nothing} &, list, {4, 5}]

(* Out: {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}} *)
```

Comment: This is great, works really well. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Another approach using `Delete`, `Extract` and `Insert`:

```
Insert[Delete[list, #], Join @@ Extract[list, #], 4] & @@ {{{4}, {5}}}
(*{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}}*)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
ClearAll[spliceParts]
spliceParts =  Module[{l = #, p = Flatten @ #2},
  l[[First @ p]] =Flatten @ l[[p]]; l[[Rest @ p]] = Nothing; l] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j}, {k, l}, {m, n, o}};

spliceParts[list, {{4}, {5}}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}}
> ```

```
spliceParts[list, { {4}, {5}, {2}}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l, e, f}, {m, n, o}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Another way of doing it, albeit not elegant

```
Join[list[[1 ;; 3]], {Join[list[[4]], list[[5]]]}, {list[[6]]}]
```

> [image: out]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe we can do the 10 ways again, why not?

Hence, one way of doing it

```
TakeList[Flatten[list], {4, 2, 3, 3, 3}]
```

> [image: out1]

Comment: The ten ways team! :)

Comment: @E.Chan-López maybe we should have a banner next to questions with 10 or more answers :) Like level of awesomeness reached or something!

Comment: That's an excellent idea, @bmf!

Answer (score 4):

As [ReplacePart](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) "uses rules in the order given", `ReplacePart` may be used to `Join` sublists at the first position specified, and then remove all but the joined sublist:

```
ReplacePart[list, Flatten[{4:> Join[Sequence@@list[[{4,5}]]], Thread[{4,5}:> Nothing]}]]

{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}}
```

As a 'pure' function:

```
ReplacePart[#1, Flatten[{#2[[1]]:> Join[Sequence@@#1[[##2]]], 
    Thread[##2:> Nothing]}]]&@@{list,{4,5}}

{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}}


ReplacePart[#1, Flatten[{#2[[1]]:> Join[Sequence@@#1[[##2]]], 
    Thread[##2:> Nothing]}]]&@@{list,{5,4,1}

{{e, f}, {g, h, i}, {k, l, j, a, b, c, d}, {m, n, o}}
```

As a function:

```
f[lst_List,pos_List]:= ReplacePart[lst, Flatten[{pos[[1]]:> Join[Sequence@@lst[[pos]]], 
                         Thread[pos:> Nothing]}]]
```

Examples

```
f[list, {4,5}]

{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}}

f[list, {6,1,3}]

{{e, f}, {j}, {k, l}, {m, n, o, a, b, c, d, g, h, i}}


list//f[#,Reverse@Range@Length@#]&//Catenate

{m, n, o, k, l, j, g, h, i, e, f, a, b, c, d}
```

where

```
list={{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i},{j}, {k, l}, {m, n, o}};
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `ApplyTo`

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j}, {k, l}, {m, n, o}};

join = list;
join[[4 ;; 5]] //= Join @@ # &;
join
```

{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j}, {k, l}, {m, n, o}};
```

OP's idea to use `FlattenAt` works with `SequenceReplace`

```
SequenceReplace[x : {_?AtomQ ..} :> x] @ FlattenAt[list, {{4}, {5}}]
```

> {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}}

A simplified version of 1066's `ReplacePart`

```
ReplacePart[{4 -> Join[list[[4]], list[[5]]], 5 -> Nothing}] @ list
```

> {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}}